# Litecoin - Is better use a good CPU or good GPU?

Tags: scrypt, mining-hardware, cpu-mining, gpu-mining

I heard in some forums that mining Litecoin is better using a good CPU (Processor), different from Bitcoin that's better mine using a good GPU (Videoboard).

I want know, this is true? For litecoin, is better buy some good processor like i7 instead a good GPU? **Litecoin really is better mined using CPU's?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any CPU can still be used to mine Litecoin, although much less effectively as a modern AMD GPU could.

Mining with a CPU gives you very bad hashrate therefore I wouldn't recommend it.
Even a high end CPU will not give you the hashrate of a mid range GPU.

You should use a graphics card (GPU) to mine litecoins or switch to another coin

Additional Information: If you decide to buy a GPU specifically for mining go for an ATI GPU as its much more effective than its nVidia counterpart.

Answer (score 3):

CPU is virtually useless for scrypt based coins like litecoin, stick to GPUs, for now.

Here is a comparison of the top GPUs you can buy for mining, with user submitted settings.

http://coinpolice.com/gpu/

Comment: is that a site from 1997? http://i.imgur.com/ukdD0ii.png

Answer (score 2):

No. A GPU will almost certainly always be faster than a CPU for Litecoin mining.

See the [Litecoin Mining Hardware Comparison chart](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison).